# QML Video shows "no content"!

Tags: qt, qml

I try to use video item to play .flv video. However, the result shows "no content". The code is as following:

```
 Video {
            id: video1;
            anchors.fill: parent;
            source: "rafael.flv";
            MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent;
            onClicked: {
                if(video1.hasVideo){
                    video1.play();
                }
                else{
                    console.log("no content");
                }
            }
        }

        focus: true;
        Keys.onSpacePressed: video1.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video1.pause() : video1.play();
        Keys.onLeftPressed: video1.seek(video1.position - 5000);
        Keys.onRightPressed: video1.seek(video1.position + 5000);
    }
```

Could anyone tell me the reason? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `source: "rafael.flv";` to `source: "file:///path/of/your/rafael.flv";`

Comment: The result remains the same!

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise edition

Comment: have you tried with another format?

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-windows.html

Comment: Yes , I have tried avi format. The result remains the same!

Comment: So the problem is the backend, do you have DirectShow installed?

Comment: What is directshow? A part of directx?

Comment: Read the following: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-windows.html and search on google :P

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem has been solved!

Comment: @Small_Bird So write an answer please :)

Comment: Install the directshow!